# How to increment (add value to) decimal in a thread-safe way?

Tags: c#, thread-safety

I have a `decimal` variable that is accessed from multiple threads at the same time. `Interlocked` class functions do not support decimals at all, so the only approach I'm left with is using `lock(){}`. It seems to be an overkill.

It there some other way to add value to `decimal` variable in a thread-safe way?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Using lock is not overkill.  It is *required*.

Structure types like System.Decimal are never atomic, it also doesn't fit the native cpu word size.  Which is why Interlocked doesn't have an overload for it either.

Answer (score 6):

No. The internal representation of `decimal` is too complex for modifications to be made with atomic instructions at the CPU level (which is what `Interlocked` does most of the time, and which is what you are interested in).

When the CPU cannot atomically handle some quantity manual locking is the only option. You get to choose the synchronization primitive (e.g. `lock` vs a mutex) but that's it.

Answer (score 3):

You can still use `InterLocked`, but then you have to convert the decimal to an `Int64`. With the conversion you have to decide how many decimal places you want to preserve for precision. So for example, you want to preserve 4 decimal places, you could do something like this:

```
//Declare up front accessible from all threads
Int64 totalAmount = 0;
        
//Inside the thread you do this
var amount = (Int64)(decimalAmount * 10000); //10.000 is to preserve 4 decimal places
Interlocked.Add(ref totalAmount, amount);
        
//After all threads have finished, go back to decimal type.
var totalDecimalAmount = totalAmount / 10000;
```

Be aware that you will lose precision, depending on how many decimal places you would like to preserve. And `Decimal.MaxValue` is `79,228,162,514,264,337,593,543,950,335` whereas `Int64.MaxValue` is  `9,223,372,036,854,775,807`. So very large numbers won't fit. Preserving 4 decimal places, the largest number before the Int64 would overflow is `9,223,372,036,854,775,807 / 10000 = 922,337,203,685,477`

I use it this way as numbers here will never go above 1,000,000,000 and I am sure that using `Interlocked` this way is faster in a `Parallel.For` loop than using a `lock` or mutex.

Comment: @MarcL.Relax. The Parallel.For I used it in, only finishes, if it is done. Then after that, the `/ 10000` operation is done. As long as totalAmount is summed in a thread safe fashion, all is fine. Not all code is a "critical section", only the summation is. `totalDecimalAmount` is evaluated after all threading is done.

Comment: Gotcha, I really should read the code-example comments more closely. Without any braces or ellipses or other pseudocode indicators, I just read it straight through.

Answer (score 2):

If you do not mind keeping the total as an object-wrapped `decimal`, you could use this approach:

```
private static object myTotal = 0M;
static void InterlockedAddTotal(decimal val) {
    object next;
    object current;
    do {
        current = myTotal;
        next = val + (decimal)current;
    } while (Interlocked.CompareExchange(ref myTotal, next, current) != current);
}
```

Although this approach does not use a lock, it wraps `decimal` in an object, which carries its own performance implications. Depending on the situation, using a lock may be cheaper.

Comment: Have you checked the performance of this solution comparing to lock approach?

Comment: You could replace myTotal with _mytotal and then create myTotal as a property which casts _myTotal into a decimal for usability, nice solution though, took forever to wrap my head around

Answer (score 1):

One way to make the assignment atomic would be by creating a class with decimal value inside and assigning the reference to the class. Assignment of class references is atomic since they are 64 (32) bit

```
class A
{
    decimal Value{get;set;}
}

var x=new A(){Value=10};
var y=new A(){Value=20};

x=y;//atomic
```

Comment: though this assignment would be atomic, however you will have to allocate a new object each time an assignment is made, which is a performance issue. Also comparing instances would require you to override `Equals()` to compare their `Value`

Comment: This won't perform an atomic increment, because two threads could read an `A`, perform their own increment and write back their own value, with the last writer winning

Answer (score 0):

If the critical section is very lightweight, you may get more performance by using a [SpinLock](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/threading/how-to-use-spinlock-for-low-level-synchronization).

Since the `decimal` is composed of  [4 ints](https://github.com/microsoft/referencesource/blob/master/mscorlib/system/decimal.cs#L145-L148) internally, even setting the value is not atomic, so you'll also need to use the same `SpinLock` when reading the value later on

```cs
public class Counter
{
    private decimal _value = 0;
    private SpinLock _lock = new (); 
    public void Increment(decimal amount)
    {
        var lockTaken = false;
        try
        {
            _lock.Enter(ref lockTaken);
            _value += amount;
        }
        finally
        {
            if (lockTaken)
            {
                _lock.Exit(true); // use true on x64
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: My understanding is that the `lock` also spins a bit before yielding the current thread (in case of contention), so I wouldn't expect to see the `SpinLock` performing better than the `lock`. Personally I don't bother with this mechanism at all.  Quoting from Albahari's [book](https://www.albahari.com/threading/part5.aspx#_SpinLock): *"A `SpinLock` makes the most sense when writing your own reusable synchronization constructs. Even then, a spinlock is not as useful as it sounds. It still limits concurrency. And it wastes CPU time doing nothing useful."*